# Extend a method in the base class c#

Tags: c#, inheritance

how do i extend a behaviour from the base class like this?

```
public class A  {
    protected virtual void foo () {
        Console.WriteLine("hi")
    }
}

public class B : A  {
    protected override void foo () {
        Console.WriteLine("hihi")
    }
}

a = new A();
a.foo() 

-> "hi"
-> "hihi"
```

When calling foo in the parent class i want to execute a behavior specific for that class while at the same time calling it in the child. Is it possible to do this with just accessing the parent?

Comment: `base.foo()`...

Comment: Wont this call the base only? I only get "hihi" when doing this.

Comment: `public class B : A  {
    protected override void foo () {
       base.foo();  Console.WriteLine("hihi");
    }
}`

Comment: No, you cannot have a call to A automatically call a method in B.  A, the parent, is unaware of its children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [base](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) keyword

```
base.myParentMethod();
```

Use that inside the overriden method if you want both actions to be performed.

Comment: oh i didnt know it was a keyword, thats neat thanks.